# How to plot crosss-sections using plot_implicit in SymPy

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I want to plot cross-sections of some equations using plot_implicit in SymPy.

Below is my sample code. There are three equations(I,J,K) and as you can see by plotting this code, there are some cross-sections.

For example, can I plot only one cross-section of I,J,K by modifing this code?
I want to analyze the area of this section for example.

Can anyone answer my quations?

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")

I = (x - 30)**2 + (y - 30)**2 -400
J = y + 2*x -60
K = (x - 10)**2 + (y - 20)**2 -200

p1 = plot_implicit(I, (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color='g')
p2 = plot_implicit(J, (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color='b')
p3 = plot_implicit(K, (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color='r')

p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.show()
```